# Bind a list of array to a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

My scenario: I am trying to bind a list of array to a repeater but its displaying system.string[]. Is there anything that I am missing here?

```
public static List<string[]> textboxs=new List<string[]>(); 

CPDRepeater.DataSource = textboxs;

CPDRepeater.DataBind();

<asp:Repeater ID="CPDRepeater" runat="server">  
    <HeaderTemplate>  
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">  
        <tr>  
            <th>  
                Employee Names  
            </th>  
        </tr>  
    </HeaderTemplate>  
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <tr>  
            <td>  
                <%# Container.DataItem %>  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
    </ItemTemplate>  
    <FooterTemplate>  
    </table>  
    </FooterTemplate>  
</asp:Repeater>
```

Example of item present in the array

```
  private static String[] a = new String[]
    {
        "CITIZ ",
        "CITIZEER ",
        "CITIAME",
        "CITIZE ",
        "CITI"

    };
```

Comment: The `Container.DataItem` is an item in the list. This is an array of string. And default string representation is `String.string[]`. Possibly you intended something like `<%# Container.DataItem[0] %>`?

Comment: or `List<string>`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev  i did eventually tried the List<string> version and it works. but the problem for me is that each string is represented as an item in the repeater. Initially i was using array of String because an array was representing an item for me. Any solution?

Comment: @FrankWitte i don't kow the number of item in the array so <%# Container.DataItem[0] %> won't be useful.

Comment: If it is `List<string[]>` then you need a nest `repeater` to bindi nternal `string[]`

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you show an example? And how would you like this to be displayed?

Comment: @FrankWitte question updated,but note here i can have several array with different number of element

Comment: Wouldn't it be handier to use a `asp:GridView` if you want to display tabular data?

Comment: If not, I think Alex's suggestion to use a nested repeater is the way to go.